# False System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException although File exists

Tags: c#, excel, exception, office-interop, comexception

I've been trying to open an EXCEL file through console but everytime I get the following exception:

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`

that the file doesn't exist or missing.Path is correct. Here is the code I get the exception:

```
string path = @"C:\User\Desktop\TerritoryFile.xlsx";
var file = new Excel.Application();
file.Visible = false;
var wb = file.Workbooks.Open(path);
```

Could it be something else apart from a wrong path

Comment: when debugging and you hover over path, what do you see?

Comment: also, can you please show some more code thanks

Comment: @SimonPrice I see the path as it is supposed to be..

Comment: @SimonPrice I've included it also in the code snippet

Comment: does that path actually exist if you go to an explorer window and try and open the file from there?

Comment: @SimonPrice yes it does

Comment: theres nothing wrong with the code, take a look at the answer below

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
string path = @"your file path ";
var file = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
file.Visible = false;
var wb = file.Workbooks.Open(path);
```